# Не могу создавать файлы в корне D:\

Tags: windows, файлы

Сегодня обнаружил что не могу создавать файлы на диске D:\ Удалять могу, создавать нет. Папки создаются. Если бы это касалось системного диска понять можно бы было. А диск то диск D... На двух других E и R все в норме.

Ошибка которая вылазит:

```
A required privilege not held by the client
```

Если что, диск Д, это отдельный винт.
Если что вот права.

[image: Права доступа]

Права были изменены только что. Для Юзерс не было полного доступа. После нажатия на "применить" система "пыталась" обрабоатать все файлы на диске, но на некоторые папки не удалось установить права.

Уж не вирус какой-то?

Comment: Возможно для начала надо сменить владельца для всех папок. Потом заменить права

Comment: Вроде уже менял. Что-то не хочет. У некоторых папок был Администратор почему-то. У некоторых TrustedInstaller почему-то. Вроде сметилось всё. Доступа к корню всё-равно нет.